# Return named ranges based on content query

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am setting up a script which will notify people of which days they are scheduled to work. I have a calendar set up with named ranges for each day (block1, block2, etc.). I need the script to go down the list of names and for each name, query which block(s) it appears in.

For example: 
Bill's name appears in blocks 1,3, and 5. So for him it will return "Block 1, Block 2, and Block 3"

I am able to pull names from the a1 notation and the reverse, and query which cell a string appears in, my problem is bridging the gap between the cell and the range that it appears in.

Comment: Roll your own solution--there isn't a method that checks if a range is a member of any named ranges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a set of functions in my library I use for checking if a cell is inside a given range, and even access the set of named ranges.

```
function IsInRange(checkRange, targetCell) {
  //--- check the target cell's row and column against the given
  //    checkrange area and return True if the target cell is
  //    inside that range
  var targetRow = targetCell.getRow();
  if (targetRow < checkRange.getRow() || targetRow > checkRange.getLastRow()) return false;

  var targetColumn = targetCell.getColumn();
  if (targetColumn < checkRange.getColumn() || targetColumn > checkRange.getLastColumn()) return false;

  //--- the target cell is in the range!
  return true;
}

function IsInNamedRange(checkCell) {
  var namedRanges = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getNamedRanges();
  for (var index = 0; index < namedRanges.length; ++index) {
    if (IsInRange(namedRanges[index].getRange(), checkCell)) {
      var rangeName = namedRanges[index].getName();
      return rangeName;
    }
  }
  return "";
}

function main() {
  var selectedCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveCell();
  var result = IsInNamedRange(selectedCell);
  if (result == "") {
    Logger.log('the selected cell ' + selectedCell.getA1Notation() + ' is not in a named range');
  } else {
    Logger.log('the selected cell ' + selectedCell.getA1Notation() + ' is in the range named ' + result);
  }
}
```